# Highlight cells that contains words only from a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

actually, I already have the formula for it, but it's not quite right.
so the formula that I have right now is this:

[image]

it could highlight values that contains "ba" and "ap", so "apple" that contains "ap" and "banana" that contains "ba" will be highlighted.

the conditional formatting formula is this (I apply it to cell B3 to B7):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$3:$F$4,B3)))>0
```

---

But, what I need is to highlight cells that contain a specific list of words like this:

[image]

It will highlight any cells that have "ba" and "ap". But, it will not highlight cells like "banana" and "apple".

So the formula should highlight cells which have only words existing in the list (e.g. highlight `ba` and `ba ap`, but don't highlight `banana`)

Comment: Perhaps instead of SEARCH use something like: `EXACT($F$3:$F$4,B3)`.

Comment: i tried changing it to =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(EXACT($F$3:$F$4,B3)))>0 but it doesn't highlight anything

Comment: For matching whole cell contents use `=COUNTIF($F$3:$F$5, $B3)`. For whole words you will need regex, which is only available in VBA. A working answer based on VBA is not a simple matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight `ba` but not `banana`, you can add a delimiter before and after the keyword (and the string).

In your example, your words are separated by `space`, so I use that.

A formula would therefore be:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&Keywords&" "," " & $A1 & " ")))
```

Note that we also add the deliminator before and after the searched reference, so as to deal with keywords at the beginning/end of the string.

Also note that `FIND` is case-sensitive.  For a case-insensitive formula, use `SEARCH`

Comment: Thanks, that works really well